# how to get snapshot all in an array flutter firebase cloud

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all of the data info. in my firebase cloud firestore but am still struggling with the **code:**

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot?>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("groups")
      .doc(groupId)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate:
          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
       crossAxisCount: 2,
     ),

          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SizedBox(
              child: snapshot.data!.get('members')[index][0],
              height: 20,
              width: 10,
            );
          });
  }),
```

[image]
**I want to snapshot all of this and display it in my app**

I don’t think I did it right cuz this is the error that I get

> ErrorDescription(
> 'Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. '
> 'In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of '
> 'vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens '
> 'when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.',

Comment: Error in the layout, print(snapshot.data!.get('members')[index][0]) before return.

Comment: Regarding this error : 'Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. ... Try adding shrinkWrap: true & physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to GridView.builder()

Comment: I think your problem is without using the widget `Text`. I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a `[0]` that isn't needed.

Change:

```
snapshot.data!.get('members')[index][0],
```

To:

```
snapshot.data!.get('members')[index],
```

Note that I'm not sure if that'll also fix your layout issue, but is definitely a problem with your code. If you still get the same layout problem after this fix, a [search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Viewports+expand+in+the+scrolling+direction+to+fill+their+container.) may provide useful results.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
snapshot.data!.get('members')[index][0],
```

to

```
Text(
  snapshot.data!.get('members')[index],
),
```